# Unable to create Alert for podReadyPercentage metrics

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, metrics, azure-alerts

I am trying to create a MetricAlert using the following script

---

```html
Set-AzContext -Subscription "f0bXXXXXXX"


$action = Get-AzActionGroup -ResourceGroupName gze-actgrp-pd-rgp-001 -Name UWDevOps_PD

$actionID = New-AzActionGroup -ActionGroupId $action.id

#Get-AzMetricDefinition -ResourceId "/subscriptions/9ca9XXXXX/resourcegroups/gze-pdi203-pd1-rgp-001/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/gze-pdi203-pd1-aks-isostr-001"

#set alert dim to pick the right options


$dim = New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2DimensionSelection -DimensionName "Kubernetes namespace" -ValuesToInclude "dv1"

$severity = 1

$RGObject = "gze-npi203-np1-rgp-001"

$ResourceId = "/subscriptions/9caXXXXXXX/resourcegroups/gze-npi203-np1-rgp-001/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/gze-npi203-np1-aks-isostr-001"

#set alert criteria and counter % Processor Time

$criteria = New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2Criteria -MetricName "podReadyPercentage" -DimensionSelection $dim
-TimeAggregation average -Operator LessThan
-Threshold 50

Set-AzContext -Subscription "921XXXX" # subID of the GZ-NP-IT-203-AKSISDUWSYS

Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "UWS-AKS203-ISOSTR-DV1-[Sev0-Critical]-Pods-Ready-Percentage less than 50-V2-CT" -ResourceGroupName $RGObject
-WindowSize 01:00:00 -Frequency 01:00:00
-TargetResourceId $ResourceId -Condition $criteria
-ActionGroup $actionID `
-Severity $severity
```

---

Error "Couldn't find a metric named podReadyPercentage."

Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: Couldn't find a metric named podReadyPercentage. Make sure the name is correct. Activity ID:
192c5e83-2b8a-4cd3-861b-da8dd2da8c1f., Code: BadRequest, Status code:BadRequest, Reason phrase: BadRequest
At line:1 char:1

Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "UWS-AKS203-ISOSTR-DV1-[Sev0-Critical]- ...

- CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2], PSInvalidOperationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.Alerts.AddAzureRmMetricAlertRuleV2Command

=========================
But as per MS doc that is the name listed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-custom-metrics?tabs=portal

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

So not sure what else I am missing here. Any help anyone?

tried to google MS docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`podReadyPercentage` metric disabled and no way to create a alert from portal, refer this [Ms Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-metric-alerts?tabs=arm-template,azure-portal#metric-alert-rules)

[image]

Alternatively, you can create an alert for the '**Pod ready percentage**' using `Log Analytics`.

1.**Go to your cluster > Logs > and run below KQL Query**

**KQL Query**

```
    KubePodInventory
    | summarize TotalPods = count(), ReadyPods = countif(ContainerID != "None" and PodStatus == "Running") by ClusterName
    | extend PodReadyPercentage = toreal(ReadyPods) / toreal(TotalPods) * 100
```

**Pod Ready Percentage**

[image]

2. Create an alert by clicking `New Alert Rule` and providing the required details to receive an alert based on the `Pod Ready Percentage`..

[image]

3. Create an `action group` or select an existing one to send an email.

[image]

You will receive an alert whenever the `Pod percentage` falls below 50%.

Comment: Awesome this is so helpful thank you again for the wonderful and timely help.

Answer (score -1):

I am unable to create alerts for any of the preview ones.. I am using Az.Monitor ver 3.1.0 and Az ver 10.0.1, if that may help..

I needed Az.Monitor ver 3.1.0 for New-AzActionGroup cmdlet to work.

Comment: Please, add your problem to your original question by editing it.